# drop down not retaining selected value after post back

Tags: asp-classic, postback

I'm using classic asp, I have a drop down list that the user selects and then presses submit. After they press submit the drop down list is going back to the default value instead of what they selected. Is there anyway to keep the state of the drop down between post backs instead of it going back to the default? Can post code sample if needed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to "select it" serverside according to the values that the user has POSTed.

```
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo" 
      <%
      if request.form("cars") = "volvo" then 
          response.write("selected") 
      end if %>
      >Volvo</option>
  <option value="Saab" 
      <%
      if request.form("cars") = "Saab" then 
          response.write("selected") 
      end if %>
      >Saab</option>
  <option value="Mercedes" 
      <%
      if request.form("cars") = "Mercedes" then 
          response.write("selected") 
      end if %>
      >Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Audi" <%
      if request.form("cars") = "Audi" then 
          response.write("selected") 
      end if %>
      >Audi</option>
</select>
```

Of course, you might want to homegrown your own function to avoid all that boilerplate.

```
<% 
sub option(value, data, select_id) 
    Response.Write("<option value=""" & value & """)
    if request.form(select_id) = value then 
        Response.Write("selected") 
    end if
    Response.Write(">" & data & "</option>")
end sub
%>
' (...)
<select id="cars">
    <% option("volvo", "Volvo", "cars") %>
    <% option("Saab", "Saab", "cars") %>
    <% option("Mercedes", "Mercedes", "cars") %>
    <% option("Audi", "Audi", "cars") %>
</select>
```

If you pass the function a blank `select_id`, it will not care about trying to select the selected item of the `select` on postback.

Comment: I used this function and it was just what I needed worked perfectly! Thank you!!

Comment: @Bmw: remember to adapt it to your needs, as there may be some things that I didn't take into account (like for example, if you use GET instead of POST) in order to keep it short. Glad it helped.

Comment: Just for the record, this accepted answer above is literally a copy and paste of the example for this concept from WW3 schools, including the car names and themes.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and plain HTML to achieve this:
HTML:
create a hidden field

Javascript:
On submit keep the selected value in hidden variable

On page load 
loop thru the drop down values and set the selected value using the hidden variable

One more variant is available in http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread105485.html

Comment: may i know why this was downvoted and without any reason explained?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but may be because it is complicating things unnecessarily by requiring javascript, when the OP problem requires only a serverside solution to take into account the posted values of the `select`.

Comment: You are welcome, we are all here to help/learn. Glad I could clarify.