# Getting HTML Dropdown selection to stay after form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, html-select

Im sure there have been postings submitted that cover material similar to this, However, I couldn't find any answers from the ones I found.

I have a form with a drop down menu and a submit button. What I am try to do is to have the menu object display the value they picked after they hit submit, example user clicks July and hits submit, the value still displays July.

What is happening is once they hit the submit button the value goes back to "January". My code is as follows.

```
<form id="NewForm" name="NewForm" method="get" action="index.asp">
    <p>
        <select name="Step1" id="Step1">
            <option value="01">January</option>
            <option value="02">February</option>
            <option value="03">March</option>
            <option value="04">April</option>
            <option value="05">May</option>
            <option value="06">June</option>
            <option value="07">July</option>
            <option value="08">August</option>
            <option value="09">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p></p>
```

Am I missing something here? This should be really simple, but I somehow seen to be missing something very elementary. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="Step1" id="Step1">
    <option <% if Step1 = "01" then %> selected <% End if %> value="01">January</option>
    <option <% if Step1 = "02" then %> selected <% End if %> value="02">February</option>                       
</select>
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you Tomer and allski, this worked! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

add "selected" to the selected option:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

In this case, March would appear as the selected option, when the dropdown is closed.

```
  <select name="Step1" id="Step1">
      <option value="01">January</option>
      <option value="02">February</option>
      <option value="03">March</option>
      <option value="04" selected>April</option>
      <option value="05">May</option>
      <option value="06">June</option>
      <option value="07">July</option>
      <option value="08">August</option>
      <option value="09">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
```

You can use add ASP code to each one of the  tag which will determine which one  had been selected.

Comment: Thank you Tomer, how would I go about adding asp code to determine the selection, I used code similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487783/drop-down-not-retaining-selected-value-after-post) but am having some issues making this work properly.